# Find specific substring while iterating through multiple file names

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, substring

I need to find the identification number of a big number of files while iterating throught them.

The file names are loaded onto a list and look like:

```
ID322198.nii
ID9828731.nii
ID23890.nii
FILEID988312.nii
```

So the best way to approach this would be to find the number that sits between `ID` and `.nii`

Because number of digits varies I can't simply select `[-10:-4]` of thee file name. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using python 3.7

Comment: does the return need to be a list of strings or a list of ints?

Comment: It has to be an `int` type. I managed to do it using rahlf23's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex (see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/5JY9og/1)):

```
import re

files = ['ID322198.nii','ID9828731.nii','ID23890.nii','FILEID988312.nii']

[re.findall(r'ID(\d+)\.nii', file)[0] for file in files]
```

Returns:

```
['322198', '9828731', '23890', '988312']
```

Answer (score 1):

to find the position of `ID` and `.nii`, you can use python's `index()` function

```
for line in file:
    idpos = 
    nilpos = 
    data =
```

or as a list of ints:

```
[ int(line[line.index("ID")+1:line.index(".nii")]) for line in file ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `rindex`:

```
s = 'ID322198.nii'
s = s[s.rindex('D')+1 : s.rindex('.')]
print(s)
```

Returns:

```
322198
```

Then apply this sintax to a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
for name in files:
    name = name.replace('.nii', '')
    id_num = name.replace(name.rstrip('0123456789'), '')
```

How this works:

```
# example
name = 'ID322198.nii'

# remove '.nii'. -> name1 = 'ID322198'
name1 = name.replace('.nii', '') 

# strip all digits from the end. -> name2 = 'ID'
name2 = name1.rstrip('0123456789') 

# remove 'ID' from 'ID322198'. -> id_num = '322198'
id_num = name1.replace(name2, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could filter the digits out, like this:

```
digits = ''.join(d for d in filename if d.isdigit())
```

That will work nicely as long as there are no other digits in the filename (e.g backups with a .1 suffix or something).